# CSS: padding-top without "stretching" border-left

Tags: html, css, border, padding

I use a table with, of course, `td`.

For one `td` I use `padding-top: 20px` and `border left:1pt`

The result is that the border on the left side is "stretched" 20 too high now. I don't see a way to fix that. Do you have any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `span` tag inside.

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td><span>Hello1</span></td>
   <td><span>Hello2</span></td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Then apply CSS:

```
<style>
  span {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! Only one problem now: I use line-height, but inside the span, the line-height doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: @Erik Add `dispaly:inline-block` on span tag